# Regression issue between org.apache.commons.commons-email and spark

Tags: scala, apache-spark, spark-submit, apache-commons-email, sparkcore

Recently I've updated the version of *`org.apache.spark.spark-core`* and *`org.apache.spark.spark-sql`* to version `2.4.3` in my **Scala application**.

Since then, my application is not able to send emails anymore. The library used for the email functionality is `org.apache.commons.commons-email`, version `1.4`. There is no much in the logs about the issue, only the stacktrace below:

```
org.apache.commons.mail.Email.sendMimeMessage(Email.java:1421)
org.apache.commons.mail.Email.send(Email.java:1448)
(...)
```

I checked the smtp host and everything is up and running (and also sending emails). Other applications with previous version of spark (2.0.1) works perfectly.

**UPDATE**

Even after returning the library versions to 2.0.1, the issue persisted. **The issue only get solved** when I also return the `${SPARK_HOME}/bin/spark-submit` back to version `2.0.1` or **any version < 2.1**.

**Is there any known issue related to Spark-submit update, that conflicts with the library `org.apache.commons.commons-email`?**

Thank you.

Comment: I am able to send mails using commons-email (1.5)& spark 2.4+, No issues. Can you post more logs ?

Comment: I have upgraded ```"org.apache.commons" % "commons-email" % "1.5"```

Comment: Hi @Srinivas, I will try to update to the version 1.5 as suggested and provide any additional logs if I have access to.
Thank you very much

Comment: Hi @Srinivas, I've updated my question. Even after returning the library versions to 2.0.1, the issue persisted. The issue only get solved when I also return the ${SPARK_HOME}/bin/spark-submit back to version 2.0.1.
Have you ever had an issue like that?